# Citrix Receiver for Mac: "You have not chosen to trust"

Tags: mac, citrix

With the latest Citrix Receiver (12.7) and MacOS (10.13 with supplemental update) versions I see the following error:

> You have not chosen to trust "/C=US/ST=/L=/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority/CN=", the issuer of the server's security certificate.

The certificate is in the keychain and it is trusted as well.

UPDATE: Downgrading to Citrix Receiver 12.4 eliminates the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You know the storefront url ? go in it with safari and check with safari how the certificate react.

I suspect SHA-1 use in the certificate, if so you might have to redo the certificate

Comment: Please explain why SHA-1 is an issue

Comment: @AndrasHatvani Did you tested with safari? you will see the certificate error